# Pandas: Group Dataframe by Key of Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Inside a Pandas Dataframe I have a column with mixed Tags as Key-Value pairs.

For Instance:

```
print(df.Tags)

0        "CostCenter": "Marketing", "Manager": "John Doe"
1        etc...
```

How can I group the Data by the Key `CostCenter`?

Comment: What is expected ouput?

Answer (score 0):

If need create new columns use:

```
print (df)
                                                Tags
0   "CostCenter": "Marketing", "Manager": "John Doe"
1                             "CostCenter": "Design"
2                                 "Manager": "John" 


import json

df1 = pd.json_normalize(('{' + df.Tags + '}').apply(json.loads))
```

---

```
import ast

df1 = pd.json_normalize(('{' + df.Tags + '}').apply(ast.literal_eval))

print (df1)
  CostCenter   Manager
0  Marketing  John Doe
1     Design       NaN
2        NaN      John
```

Or create only new column `CostCenter` use:

```
df['CostCenter'] = ('{' + df.Tags + '}').apply(ast.literal_eval).str.get('CostCenter')
print (df)
                                                Tags CostCenter
0   "CostCenter": "Marketing", "Manager": "John Doe"  Marketing
1                             "CostCenter": "Design"     Design
2                                 "Manager": "John"        None
```

Last is possible aggreagte by column `CostCenter`:

```
df.groupby('CostCenter').sum()
```